# R - Looping through files in a directory and cross reference a column to all other tables

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, summary

I need to read all files in a directory that ends with XLS. I have used this code below:

```
filenames <- list.files("temp", pattern="*.XLS")
paste("temp",filenames, sep="/")
ldf <- lapply(filenames,read.table)
ldf
```

Now I need to access each table separately and cross reference data from column 2 from each table with all other tables and check the frequency of it in other tables. I have tried the lines below but nothing really works:

```
ldf1.summary$V2
ldf1$V2 
dataset [,Gene]
```

I'm new to **R** and I have to submit the solution in a couple of days. Any help?

Comment: Thanks @Brian Tompsett